# ImageURL showing white image when "null"

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to show a default imaged named "Tap_Edit_Profile" when the image URL is empty, but i am not sure why when its empty, it shows a white picture. Is it something I missed out in my code?

```
 if let imageURL = self.currentAgent.userPictureURL {
            if imageURL != "null" {
                self.userPicture.setImageWithURLString(string: imageURL, shouldFadeIn: true)

            }
            else {
                self.userPicture.image = UIImage(named: "Tap_Edit_Profile")     }
```

below is my setImageWithURLString function:

```
    func setImageWithURLString(string: String?, placeholderImage: UIImage? = nil ,shouldFadeIn fade: Bool, withDuration duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, completionBlock: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

    if let string = string {
        if let url: URL = URL(string: string) {
            if SDWebImageManager.shared().cachedImageExists(for: url) || fade == false {
                self.alpha = 1
            } else {
                self.alpha = 0
            }

            self.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, options: .retryFailed, completed: { (image, error, type, url) in
                completionBlock?()
                if type == SDImageCacheType.none {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                        self.alpha = 1
                    })
                } else {
                    self.alpha = 1
                }
            })
            return
        }
    }
    if fade {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: { self.alpha = 1 })
    }
}
```

the imageURL doesnt have any images, therefore shouldnt it show my default image of "Tap_Edit_Profile"??
thx in advance guys

Comment: Not enough info, since none of us knows what `setImageWithURLString` is, what `imageURL` is, etc.

Comment: have added the function, sorry for missing out the setImageWithURLString function

Comment: can you please show image_url in your json when you say its null ? is it <null> or "null" or null ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are  using  SDWebImage for load the image from the url. By default the library provide an option to set the default image . Here is the code

```
self.profilePicture.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "url"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Tap_Upload_Photo.png"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of your if logic is wrong. You should change it to

```
if let imageURL = self.currentAgent.userPictureURL, !imageUrl.isEmpty {
    self.userPicture.setImageWithURLString(string: imageURL, shouldFadeIn: true)
}  else {
    self.userPicture.image = UIImage(named: "Tap_Edit_Profile")     
}
```

Comment: tried changing it but still showing up a white image

Comment: @WilliamLoke did you recheck your image name, if it has type `.png` or you set it in the `Assets`, it will show.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it and thought to share the answer if anyone meet the same problem in future. I used the following code

```
    if let imageURL = self.currentAgent.userPictureURL {
        if imageURL != "null" {
            self.profilePicture.setImageWithURLString(string: imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Tap_Upload_Photo"), shouldFadeIn: true, withDuration: 0, completionBlock: nil)
        }

        else {
            self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(named: "Tap_Upload_Photo")
        }
    }
```

maybe the else isn't necessary. Feel free to edit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the control is reaching the below line of code or not

  self.userPicture.image = UIImage(named: "Tap_Edit_Profile")
- Check the `userPicture` IBOutlet connection
- Check if you passing correct name of the image "Tap_Edit_Profile"